# Windows Mobile Bluetooth access on either Microsoft or Widcomm Stack

Tags: java, dll, windows-mobile, bluetooth, java-native-interface

I have a Java application that is running on a Windows mobile device.  I need to be able to turn Bluetooth on and off so it is executing some native code to do this.  The problem is that I am trying it out on a new device (the HTC HD2) and the native code doesn't work.  The reason for this is that the HD2 device is using the Widcomm Bluetooth stack, whereas the other device was using the Microsoft stack.

I have now found a way of activating Bluetooth on the HD2 device using the Widcomm SDK.  However this native code needs to be able to run on any device, so somehow I need to be able to make the decision at runtime which code to run based on which bluetooth stack is present.

Question 1: how can I determine programmatically which stack is present?

Question 2: if I include the header file required for the Widcomm stack and try to run it on a device that doesn't use it the code fails.  How can I compile the dll so that it only includes that header file if the Widcomm dll exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you can have to do it all dynamically:

1. Declare prototypes for the necessary Widcomm functions in your own code.
2. Use `LoadLibrary` to load the Widcomm dll.
3. If the `LoadLibrary` call fails then you know you're on a Microsoft stack and you can run the standard Microsoft stack functions.
4. If the `LoadLibrary` succeeds you're on the Widcomm stack and can use the Widcomm functions.

It might be a bit messy depending on how many functions you need from the Widcomm header, but you can't statically compile in references to those functions, as it will try and load it and not find it (which is probably why you're seeing the crash).

That's truly terrible that the Bluetooth stack craziness exists on Windows Mobile as well. Thought that was confined to the desktop.

Comment: Well, different OS's I'm not THAT caught up over, but within a single vendor/platform that's just ridiculous. BlueZ is it, regardless of modern Linux version, OSX is the same, as is Android, as is iOS. Windows appears to be the only OS where 2 installs of the exact same version of the exact same OS can have different interfaces to the Bluetooth stack.

Comment: Yep.  Got'a wonder who's making some of those decisions - or how they are making those decisions???

Comment: They are making decisions? :)

Comment: 2Funny ... I think they brought out their pet monkey, who's simply throwing feces at the dart board ... the proverbial "let's see what sticks."